# How do you invoke javascript function from an apache velocity *.vm file?

Tags: javascript, velocity, confluence

I am currently using Confluence 4.3 and I'm trying to add either an HTML button or HTML link that will invoke a javascript function.

How can this be achieved?

Specifically, there is a file called "searchpanel.vm" within Confluence which is a simple velocity template that defines criteria used to refine your confluence searches.

I wish to a button in the search panel that will invoke a javascript function.  How do I do this?

Comment: you can just use a script tag and put a function call inside it, or use velocity to generate onload for document. there is nothing special to invoke js from velocity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special notation for writing Javascript in Velocity. Just write as you normally do in any HTML file. An example would be :

```
    <form>
    #if ($searchVisible)
        <div id = "searchLinkContainer" >
            <a href="javascript:searchFunction()">Click here</a> to search.
        </div>  
    #end    
    </form>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">   
        function searchFunction () {
            //Do search
        }
    </script>
```

Note that if you include the  tag inside a conditional statement in Velocity and it doesn't get traversed, the script will not be available in the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is just a templating language/engine, which can print whatever you want. Just write the HTML that you would normally use regardless of the fact that you're in a `.vm` file.